# Is there an official 5e equivalent of the the Blinkback Belt from Pathfinder?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, magic-items, throwing-things

I have been playing around with an idea for a dagger-throwing character in 5e. I was wondering if there was an official version of the [Blinkback Belt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-blink-back/) from *Pathfinder*. I feel that it could be an interesting build.

The belt holds either 2 one-handed weapons or 4 light weapons which, when drawn and thrown, are teleported back to the belt. I am more interested in the teleporting aspect, i.e. the character can spend his action/bonus action to throw some daggers, and then doesn't have to worry about retrieving them if they miss. Think of it as a John Woo movie in D&D.

I have looked around online but unfortunately with so much homebrew content out there I was not able to decipher what was considered official or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61789/discussion-between-matthew-perryman-and-nautarch).

Comment: Unfortunately no so as a DM it is one of my home brew items I call it the belt of returning, I believe there is a similar version on the internet. It is an attuned item for daggers or similar size weapons. my version allows up to 4 daggers to be held in the belt, on being thrown and striking something the dagger instantly reappears back in the belt. This means the same dagger can reappear and be thrown a second time. I price it as an uncommon item between 150-300 gp depending where the party are but generally if there is a rogue in the party I have it be found early on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 5E, there are only a handful of sources for magic items that are official - primarily the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, and the appendices of published adventures.

After looking through all of these, the answer to your question is: **No. The Blinkback Belt does not have an exact equivalent in D&D 5e.**

There are a few magic items that have a similar effect though (in that they can be thrown multiple times). However, all of these return the item to your hand, not your belt - a small but perhaps noteworthy difference.

From the DMG:

- The [*Dwarven Thrower*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dwarven-thrower) (Very Rare Warhammer, only usable by a dwarf)
  can be thrown, and immediately flies back to your hand afterwards.
- [*Whelm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/whelm) is a legendary sentient Warhammer (only usable by a dwarf) that
  has the same feature

From the *Princes of the Apocalypse* adventure:

- A [*Storm Boomerang*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/storm-boomerang) returns to your hand if you miss (but not if
  you hit)

Finally, the closest to what you're looking for is probably in the adventure *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*:

- The [*Bracer of Flying Daggers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bracer-of-flying-daggers) functions similarly to the
  Blinkback Belt (albeit more limited in what weapons can be equipped
  to it, but allowing an additional attack):

  > This armband appears to have thin daggers strapped to it. As an action, you can pull up to two magic daggers from the bracer and immediately hurl them, making a ranged attack with each dagger. A dagger vanishes if you don’t hurl it right away, and the daggers disappear right after they hit or miss. The bracer never runs out of daggers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100607/discussion-on-answer-by-guildsbounty-is-there-an-official-5e-equivalent-of-the-t).

Answer (score 5):

The [*bracer of flying daggers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bracer-of-flying-daggers) was released in the *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* module (p. 191). It lets you use an action to draw and throw 2 magic daggers from it, and the daggers disappear after they hit or miss, or if you don't throw them right away. The bracer never runs out of daggers. These daggers count as magical.

It's not exactly the same (you can only use it for the daggers the bracer itself supplies - you can't put your own weapons there) but that's as close to the 3.5 Bracers of Endless Daggers or the Blinkback Belt from Pathfinder that I've found so far.

Comment: This comes close, but not quite: you can't use this to throw anything but magic Daggers. That is, the value of a Blinkback Belt is that you can throw your own +3 Flaming Daggers/Shuriken/Throwing Axes and get a) the returning property for free and b) avoid having to have one hand free (since weapons return to belt, not your hand).