# Is there any reasonable way to use a magic weapon as a throwing-weapon specialist?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, optimization, throwing-things

*Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything* includes two features relevant to a throwing-weapon specialist:

- The artificer’s *Returning Weapon* infusion, which can be applied to a nonmagical thrown weapon to give it a +1 bonus to attack and damage and allow it to return to your hand after an attack. (This infusion also appeared in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*.)
- The Thrown Weapon Fighting Style, available to several classes, which allows a fresh throwing weapon to be drawn with every attack.

However, neither of these allows you to consistently use a magic weapon, nor does either provide a way to avoid losing a magic weapon you throw. *Returning Weapon* is explicitly incompatible with weapons that are already magical (it does make it count as magic, which is good, but not the same as being able to use a magic weapon one finds). Thrown Weapon Fighting can be used with a magical weapon, but provides no mechanism for using that weapon again, so unless you have a supply of them, that’s just one attack, plus you better make sure to collect your weapon again after, which can be a problem.

Is there anything that allows a thrower to use, say, a random magic spear they find, as a thrown weapon? One could, of course, include magic weapons that have a built-in *Returning* property in addition to other properties (e.g. *Dwarven Thrower*), but that isn’t the same thing. So it seems that, despite recent material to improve it, and despite the character-building investment required by those features, throwing is still a uniquely disadvantageous combat style, with insurmountable drawbacks that apply to no other style.

Is this analysis correct? Or are there options I am missing that address this?

Answer (score 11):

### Form a Bond with the weapon as an Eldritch Knight

The Eldritch Knight fighter subclass includes the Weapon Bond feature with which you can form a bond with up to two weapons (no limitations on being magical or not) and

> If it is on the same plane of existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand.
>
> — *Player's Handbook*, p. 75; [Eldritch Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/subclasses/Eldritch-Knight)

This obviously eats into your bonus action, and you can only return one weapon per bonus action, so works poorly with two weapon fighting or even just getting too many attacks and wanting to throw things with each of them.

(This is the only of the methods for [returning weapons in general](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/171883/52137) which works with general magic items.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be the only method that's by the book.

Comment: +1, but yeah, while 1/turn is vastly superior to 1/retrieval, this isn’t really workable. A magic weapon may not be mandatory, but the inability to use one at all certainly seems significant.