# Are there any magic weapons that return when thrown?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

As someone who's ended up throwing quite a lot of daggers at enemies, it would be nice to find one that magically comes back to me, so I don't have to worry about retrieving them or running out.

I know there's the *returning weapon* artificer infusion, but without an artificer in the party, it may be difficult to acquire one of those. I've also seen the *bracer of flying daggers*, but that's a Rare item (I imagine mostly because it lets you attack twice per action).

Are there any other ways to have a dagger, or other item with the Thrown property, magically return after I throw it?

Comment: Related: "[How to make a handaxe return to my hand after being thrown?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171869)" and "[Is there any reasonable way to use a magic weapon as a throwing-weapon specialist?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/184076)" and "[Is there an official 5e equivalent of the the Blinkback Belt from Pathfinder?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103023)" That last one may actually effectively answer your question

Comment: @draconis  You mention thrown weapons, but would you want also details of weapons with ammunition, too? - i.e. that it is about ranged weapons, not just thrown.

Answer (score 14):

### Dwarven Thrower

There is at least one weapon that returns when thrown in the DMG (p. 167), the **Dwarven Thrower**.

> **DWARVEN THROWER** *Weapon (warhammer), very rare (requires attunement by a dwarf)* You gain a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. It has the **thrown** property with a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet. When you hit with a ranged attack using this weapon,
> it deals an extra ld8 damage or, if the target is a giant, 2d8 damage. **Immediately after the attack, the weapon flies back to your hand.**

This weapon has been in the game since the original brown books D&D. However, it requires you to be a dwarf; and it is very rare, even more rare than the *Bracers of Flying Daggers* you already identified as a possible solution.

As an alternative, you could also consider to take three levels in the Fighter (Eldrich Knight) class, and gain the *Weapon Bond* feature, that allows you to bond any weapon and gain this ability with it:

> If it is on the same plane of existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand.

Answer (score 4):

May be a little late but there is the Weapon Bond Feature of the Eldritch Knight:

> Weapon Bond
> At 3rd level, you learn a ritual that creates a magical bond between yourself and one weapon. You perform the ritual over the course of 1 hour, which can be done during a short rest. The weapon must be within your reach throughout the ritual, at the conclusion of which you touch the weapon and forge the bond.
>
> Once you have bonded a weapon to yourself, you can't be disarmed of that weapon unless you are incapacitated. If it is on the same plane of existence, **you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand.**
>
> You can have up to two bonded weapons, but can summon only one at a time with your bonus action. If you attempt to bond with a third weapon, you must break the bond with one of the other two.

Comment: Groody mentioned it in their answer, but you provided more details.